# What happens when I instantiate class in Python?

Tags: python, variables, class

Could you clarify some ideas behind Python classes and class instances?

Consider this:

```
class A():
    name = 'A'

a = A()

a.name = 'B' # point 1 (instance of class A is used here)

print a.name
print A.name
```

prints:

```
B
A
```

if instead in `point 1` I use class name, output is different:

```
A.name = 'B' # point 1 (updated, class A itself is used here)
```

prints:

```
B
B
```

Even if classes in Python were some kind of prototype for class instances, I'd expect already created instances to remain intact, i.e. output like this:

```
A
B
```

Can you explain what is actually going on?

Comment: A day on SO wouldn't be complete without a new duplicate of this question. Reading tutorials or books to learn a programming language is soooo last year...

Comment: I've searched through SO first and couldn't find answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the right way in Python to create fields of an instance (rather than class fields) is using the `__init__` method. I trust that you know that already.

Python does not limit you in assigning values to non-declared fields of an object. For example, consider the following code:

```
class Empty: pass
e = Empty()
e.f = 5
print e.f # shows 5
```

So what's going in your code is:

1. You create the class `A` with a static field `name` assigned with `A`.
2. You create an instance of `A`, `a`.
3. You create a new field for the object `a` (but not for other instances of `A`) and assign `B` to it
4. You print the value of `a.name`, which is unique to the object `a`.
5. You print the value of the static field `A.name`, which belongs to the class

Answer (score 1):

You also should look at these SO threads for further explanations:
[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/python-static-variable)
[In Python how can I access "static" class variables within class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/in-python-how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-class-methods)

And an official tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#SECTION0011320000000000000000

Keep in mind that the assignment "=" operator in python behaves differently than C++ or Java:
http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example may make things more help clarify. Recall that Python names are not storage (as variables are in other languages) but references to storage. You can find what a name refers to with id(name). The identity operator `x is y` tells whether two names point at the same object.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     name = 'A'
... 
>>> x = A()
>>> A.name is x.name
True
>>> x.name = 'fred'  # x.name was bound to a new object (A.name wasn't)
>>> A.name is x.name
False
>>> x = A()          # start over
>>> A.name is x.name
True                 # so far so good
>>> A.name = 'fred'
>>> A.name is x.name 
True                 # this is somewhat counter-intuitive
```