# NameError when the name is defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nameerror

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-902791409a52> in <module>()
     57         ObjectLists.sounds[5].play_sound()
     58 
---> 59 class Scale:
     60     scales = [Scale.zv, Scale.newton]
     61     screening = False

<ipython-input-1-902791409a52> in Scale()
     58 
     59 class Scale:
---> 60     scales = [Scale.zv, Scale.newton]
     61     screening = False
     62     newtoncount = 0

NameError: name 'Scale' is not defined
```

Can't for the life of me figure out what this is about. The name 'Scale' is defined, however, the interpreter's never wrong. What am I  missing?

**EDIT:** When I run:

```
class things:
    poo = [things.roughage(), things.towels()]
    @staticmethod
    def roughage():
        return('health')

    @staticmethod
    def towels():
        return('dryness')

print(things.poo)
```

it raises a NameError; things is not defined.

However when I run:

```
class things:
    @staticmethod
    def roughage():
        return('health')

    @staticmethod
    def towels():
        return('dryness')

class holder:
    poo = [things.roughage(), things.towels()]

print(holder.poo)
```

there's no error and output is as expected.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for the class 'Scale'? As well as how it is executed.

Comment: How is the interpreter supposed to know what `Scale` is before you've finished defining it? For what it's worth, I can't figure it out any better than the interpreter can, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> The name 'Scale' is defined, however, the interpreter's never wrong

Is it defined though? You're using `Scale` within its own definition. At the time that the interpreter accesses line 60 it hasn't defined `Scale` yet. Let alone it's attributes `zv` and `newton`. Instead, you could try defining `zv` and `newton` before defining `scales`.

```
class Scale:
    screening = False
    newtoncount = 0
    zv = 'zv'
    newton = 'newton'
    scales = [zv, newton]

scale = Scale()
print scale.scales
```

Edit: 
I'm glad you got something working (judging from your last edit). In your working example there is no error because `things` is fully defined before it's used in the definition of `holder`.

Another way you could achieve what you seem to be looking for would be by using the [__init__](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) function in your class definition and accessing `poo` on an *instance* of `things` instead of the class itself.

```
class things():
    def __init__(self):
        self.poo = [self.roughage(), self.towels()]
    @staticmethod
    def roughage():
        return('health')
    @staticmethod
    def towels():
        return('dryness')

holder = things()  # create an instance of things
print(holder.poo)
```

This way you don't need to split up your definitions into two classes.

I don't know anything about your full implementation of these classes but I want to point two key differences in these two implementations.

Your example with `Scales` and the first implementation of `things` declare class level attributes whereas my implementation declares `poo` as an instance level attribute.

A quick search turned up the following links on the subject:

- [What is the difference between class and instance variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959097/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-variables-in-python)
- http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd tried relocating the `scales` list at multiple positions in my `Scales` class, and also defining `zv` and `newton` before adding them to the `scales` list. However, these attempts made no difference. In my frustration I didn't really think about relocating the scales list, and that seems to be what works.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can't use something until it's been created. The interpreter works in a fairly linear top-down fashion, so even something as simple as

```
foo()
def foo():
    print('hi')
```

will raise a `NameError`.

To create a class, the interpreter executes the class definition and then binds the resulting class object to the supplied name. Your first `things` example tries to use the name `things` before it's bound to an object and before the object itself exists. It also tries to call those static methods before they exist.

I realise your code is just a toy example, but it's not a very typical Python class: it has no instance attributes, and no normal methods, only static ones. Sure, the language lets you do that, but it's much more common to make classes that are used to create instances.

FWIW, it's possible to initialise a class attribute inside the `__init__` method. Of course that's useless if you have no intention of creating instances, but I'll show a brief example anyway.

```
class Things():
    poo = None

    def __init__(self):
        if Things.poo is None:
            print('Initialising poo...')
            Things.poo = [self.roughage(), self.towels()]

    @staticmethod
    def roughage():
        return('health')
    @staticmethod
    def towels():
        return('dryness')

print(Things.poo)

h1 = Things()
p = h1.poo
print(p, id(p))

p = Things.poo
print(p, id(p))

h2 = Things()  
p = h2.poo
print(p, id(p))
```

**output**

```
None
Initialising poo...
['health', 'dryness'] 3072932652
['health', 'dryness'] 3072932652
['health', 'dryness'] 3072932652
```

The initialisation could also be done with

```
Things.poo = [Things.roughage(), Things.towels()]
['health', 'dryness'] 3072924460
```