# What is the difference between the following piece of code declaration in python

Tags: python

in python if i used a variable outside any class method it available throughout other methods and if i use the **init** method with self it basically does the same (or as it seems ) can anybody explain the difference between them . and when it is suitable to use either of the approach

```
class gaurab():
    value1=1
    value2=2
    value3=3

values=gaurab()

class something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1=1
        self.value2=100
    def p(self):
        print self.value1

svalues=something()

print values.value1

print svalues.p()
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong! And you also want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959097/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes directly declared in a class are called class attributes.
Like in your example(though indentation and some syntax is wrong), value1 , value2 and value3 are class attributes for class gaurab.

Attributes declared inside other attributes are instance attributes and are bound to the class attribute in which they are declared.
Like the value1 and value2 variables are bound to **init** in class something.

The class attributes are compared to static variables found in statically typed languages as C++, JAVA etc.
Class attributes are shared by all the instances of class so only one copy of such attributes is made (unlike for instance attributes where each instance of class has its own copy of instance variables).

When instance of class `something` is made, `something`'s `__init__` method is executed, receiving the new instance in its `self` parameter. This method creates two instance attributes: `value1` and `value2`. Then this instance is assigned into the instance variable, so it's bound to a thing with those two instance attributes.

For example :

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Alist=[]    #It is an instance attribute

    Blist=[]             #It is a class attribute
```

For this class definition, when we create 2 class instances as :

```
var1 = foo()
var2 = foo()
```

The `Blist` attribute is shared by both `var1` and `var2` but `Alist` attribute is different for both of them. So, if we operate the following :

```
var1.Alist.append(1)
var1.Blist.append(10)
var2.Alist.append(2)
var2.Blist.append(20)
```

The output of

```
print(var1.Alist)
print(var1.Blist)
print(var2.Alist)
print(var2.Blist)
```

will be :

```
[1]
[10]
[2]
[10,20]
```

This is because `Blist` variable was shared by both `var1` and `var2` So, changes in `var1.Blist` affected `var2.Blist` and vice versa.
But, `var1.Alist` and `var2.Alist` are independent of each other.

So, if you want an attribute to be common to all the instances of the class, then you declare it as class attribute(which if not what is often required) else, you can declare it as instance attribute.