# Basic object oriented implementation in python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, self

Hello I am learning python and I have this working code but in most of Object Oriented examples of python, I see people use extra stuff and I am not sure why do we need those.

I will try to explain my question with comments in the code.

```
class Node:

    data = none
    next = none

# Question1: Why do we have these variables outside of 
# __init__ fucntion? what are their applications? 

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.next = None
    def display(self):
        next = self
        while next.next:
            print next.data, "->",
            next = next.next
        print next.data

# Question2: Do we need getter setter functions to access 
# the attributes above? I was able to remove a node with 
# simple function and it worked well

def denode(node):
    node.next = node.next.next


# Question 3: for many implementation samples of a linked
# list or something that uses Node, I see that example
# uses another class, but in the example below I was able
# to create a linked list without any trouble. why do we 
# need a separate class to create a linked list?


#ex
node1 = Node(123)
node2 = Node(134)
node3 = Node(139)
node4 = Node(148)
node1.next=node2
node2.next= node3
node1.display()
denode(node1)
node1.display()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of using other classes to create a linked list for question 3?

Comment: `next = self`... this looks like a bad idea!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque why?

Comment: Isn't re-assigning a builtin generally a bad idea @juanpa.arrivillaga? Are you asking 'why' because you think that in this case it is not? then Why?

Comment: Ahhh yes. I didn't realize initially. I asked because I wanted to know what you meant. Well, in a local scope re-assigning a built-in is significantly less likely to cause problems. I admit, I've used `next` as a local variable a few times. Probably, it is best to just use `next_` or `_next`.

Comment: @KevinFang https://www.codefellows.org/blog/implementing-a-singly-linked-list-in-python/

Comment: that is great explanation

Comment: @AshishKumar that link is not a good example of idiomatic Python. The author also suggested using getters and setters in the comments, which is not Pythonic. In python, you use the  `property` decorator, and only when you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The variables outside the `__init__` method are called class variables and inside the method are called instance variables. This will answer your question: [What is the difference between class and instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959097/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-variables)
2. In python, all variables are public so you don't need getter setter methods unless you want them in order to protect the variable value or you want to process / validate the value before setting / getting the variable. More is here: [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)
3. There is a design flaw in your code. The class `Node` represents one node. So, if I had to use this implementation I would expect all methods of `Node` would be in one node scope including `display`. You implemented `Node.display()` to display the whole linked list and therefor you "don't need" a `LinkedList` class. I think it is better to add a `LinkedList` class with a `head` variable to hold the first node and a `display` method just like you wrote to make it more intuitive.