# Why can I override a class variable? Pointer being overridden?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, instance-variables, class-variables

I have this bit of code:

```
class Car:
    wheels = 4


if __name__ == "__main__":
    car = Car()
    car2 = Car()
    print(car2.wheels)
    print(car.wheels)
    car.wheels = 3
    print(car.wheels)
    print(car2.wheels)
```

Which outputs:

```
4
4
3
4
```

Here "wheels" is defined as a class variable. Class variables are shared by all objects. However I can change its value for a SPECIFIC instance of that class?

Now I know to modify the class variable I need to use the class name:

```
Car.wheels = 3
```

I'm still confused as to how/why this happens. Am I creating an instance variable or am I overwriting the class variable for that instance using:

```
car.wheels = 3
```

-- Or something else?

Comment: Attributes are looked up first on the instance, then the class. So, when you set an attribute of the same name on an instance, it goes in the instance's `__dict__` and overrides the class attribute when looked up on that instance.

Comment: You might find this answer from [What is the difference between class and instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959269/8944057) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you do not override the class attribute `wheels`, but create an instance attribute named `wheels` for the object `car` and set it to 3.

This can be verified using [the special `__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__):

```
>>> class Car:
...   wheels=4
... 
>>> c1 = Car() 
>>> c2 = Car()
>>> 
>>> c1.wheels=3
>>> c1.wheels
3
>>> c2.wheels
4
>>> c1.__dict__
{'wheels': 3}
>>> c2.__dict__
{}
```