# recursive constructor, variable sharing

Tags: python

trying to walk through a directory and subdirectories I am getting error in the following code.
Here, I am trying to call the constructor recursively.

```
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

class CovPopulate:
    fileList = list()
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        for f in os.listdir(self.path):
            if isfile(join(self.path,f)):
                if f.endswith(".txt"):
                    fileList.append(join(self.path,f))
            else:
                CovPopulate(f)
```

Traceback : -

```
 CovPopulate(r"C:\temp")
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
CovPopulate(r"C:\temp")


 File "C:/fuzzingresults/CovPopulate.py", line 11, in __init__
      fileList.append(join(self.path,f))
       NameError: global name 'fileList' is not defined
```

but, I have alread defined the fileList = list()

This time I 've checked for the synch errors :/

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I can see absolutely no reason to make this a class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, i know there is not reason, but classes help in reuse, I could just make a function and be done with it, but I prefer to make seperate classes for code, classes help in namespaces because imports can clash. ALl my utility functions are defined in seperate classes in one single file. 

Is there something wrong in doing this?

Comment: @Tichodroma, what?
recursive constructor?.. just  for learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filelist` is defined in the namespace of the `CovPopulate` class. I suggest to access it through `self`. Besides, I got problem when `f` is not a file nor a directory (symlinks, pipes, ...) so I added the `isdir` check. Finally, I got the code to work only if I pass the absolute path to `CovPopulate`. My `__init__` function looks like this:

```
def __init__(self,path):
    self.path = path
    for f in os.listdir(self.path):
        if isfile(join(self.path,f)):
            if f.endswith(".txt"):
                self.fileList.append(join(self.path,f))
        elif isdir(join(self.path,f)):
            CovPopulate(join(self.path,f))
```

Comment: it won't work. I tried your code and did this. besides, fileList is already defined inside the class itself.. why is a self needed?

Comment: Do you still get a `NameError`?

Comment: By the way, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/in-python-how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-class-methods

Comment: yes the post makes sense, i get it. I need to use static var for it to work.