# NameError (global name ... is not defined) when using reload()

Tags: python, pyqt

Unfortunately I get a `NameError` on reloading a module in Python 2.7.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class MyQThread(QtCore.QThread):
    import foo
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        reload(foo)
        print("Reloaded")
        #...do something
```

And when I use

```
thread = MyQThread()
thread.start()
```

I got this in the shell:

> NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined

Any advice?

Comment: what is this myModule?

Comment: Why would you ever put an `import` statement in a class?

Comment: @Kalyan: myModule is a name of some example module...I'll change this to foo

Comment: then, that means that, its unable to import that module

Comment: @BartoszKP: sorry for typos. Now the code should work. Unfortunately I can't copy-paste the code.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/in-python-how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-class-methods) and then move the `import` into the global scope.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I've put it there because my thought was to use this class as thread. And after the thread stopped on some action the namespace of import should be cleared (as my understanding of how threading and importing works).

Comment: @MrPickel Surely you can verify what you post before posting, and that's all what this is about. If you don't want to help yourself with Ctrl-C Ctrl-V fine by me :)

Answer (score 1):

An `import` statement is a type of assignment. By executing it inside the `class` statement, you are defining a *class* attribute named `foo` that is bound to the module. You would have to use `reload(MyQThread.foo)`.

That said, there is little benefit to putting the `import` statement in the class definition; just move the `import` to the global scope.

Comment: I need to import a module by pressing a button inside my GUI. And when it's pressed again the module should be reloaded. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Just as you are doing; I'm saying the *initial* import may as well be outside the class. It will work the same either way, but there should be some significant reason to put the import in a non-standard location.