# Variables inside and outside of object methods

Tags: python, class, object, variables, methods

I have just started to learn about classes and objects in Python and I came to following problem

It doesnt seem to work with variable n in methods I defined in some cases:

for example:

```
def play(self):
    if n < 4:
        n += 1
        self.mood = moods[n]
    else:
        self.mood = self.mood
```

this throws and error that n is not defined on line "if n < 4:" but if I erase this part "n += 1" error does not appear. But even after that it doesnt seem to update variable n if I use it in method:

```
def new_mood(self):
    n = random.randint(0,2)
    self.mood = moods[n]
```

Am I missing some fundamental knowledge here?

```
import random

moods = ['terrible', 
         'bad', 
         'neutral', 
         'good', 
         'great']

n = random.randint(0,2)

class animals:

    def __init__(self, species, name, mood):
        self.species = species
        self.name = name
        self.mood = mood

    def default_mood(self):
        self.mood = moods[2]

    def new_mood(self):
        n = random.randint(0,2)
        self.mood = moods[n]    

    def play(self):
        if n < 4:
            n += 1
            self.mood = moods[n]
        else:
            self.mood = self.mood


Max = animals('Dog', 'Max', moods[n])
Princess = animals('Cat', 'Princess', moods[n])


print(Max.name + ' mood is ' + Max.mood)
print(Princess.name + ' mood is ' + Princess.mood)

Max.new_mood()
Max.play()

Princess.play()


print(Max.name + ' mood is ' + Max.mood)
print(Princess.name + ' mood is ' + Princess.mood)

print(Max.mood)

print(Max.name + ' mood is ' + Max.mood)
print(Princess.name + ' mood is ' + Princess.mood)
```

Comment: reopened because the proposed duplicate didn't make sense here - the op doesn't want a global obviously.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how so? `n` is a global variable they are trying to modify, is it not?

Comment: @UnholySheep not it is not - what the OP wants might as well be an instance attribute.

Comment: @Marek are you sure you want a global variable here ? Is the mood of one `animal` instance really supposed to depend on the previous calls to `new_mood()` and/or `play()` on __any__ `animal`  instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: This is not caused by classes but by the way scoping works in Python. Any assignment to a name makes that name a local variable, shadowing any global ones of the same name.

Use `global` or `nonlocal` to explicitly refer to names from global or containing scope. Use class attributes to refer to names from class scope.

---

Consider this minimal example without a class:

```
>>> n = 5
...
>>> def foo():
...    if n < 10:
...        n += 1
...
>>> foo()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

Notice how the error says **local**  variable? The `n` inside `foo` is not the global `n`! Since the local `n` is not initialised until its assignment, it cannot be used in the comparison beforehand. You would get, and probably also expect, the same error if the global `n` did not exist.

Whenever a name is assigned to in a scope, that automatically makes this name local to that scope. Note that this affects the entire scope - including occurrences before the assignment. If you do only an assignment, that only changes the local name - which is thrown away at the end of the scope.

If you want to modify a name in an outer scope, you have to tell Python. The `global` and `nonlocal` keywords exist for this:

```
>>> def foo():
...    global n     # n refers to the global name n for the entire scope
...    if n < 10:   # works, we compare against the global n
...        n += 1   # modifies the global n, no introduction of local n
```

A related but slightly different use cases are variables specific to a class. For example, `n` may be a feature of all `animals` *without* affecting, say, all `humans`.

Such class attributes are defined in the body of the class. You can refer to them by the class' name, similar to how you would fetch a method:

```
class Animals:
    n = 0

    def new_mood(self):
        # we want the 'n' of Animals
        Animals.n = random.randint(0,2)
        self.mood = moods[Animals.n]
```

There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51668692/5349916) to use class attributes, depending on how one wants to handle modifying and subclassing.