# Why is the Class variable not updating for all its instances?

Tags: python, oop, instance, class-variables

I'm learning about classes and don't understand this:

```
class MyClass:
    var = 1

one = MyClass()
two = MyClass()

print(one.var, two.var) # out: 1 1
one.var = 2

print(one.var, two.var) # out: 2 1
```

I thought that class variables are accessible by all instances, why is the Class variable not updating for all its instances?

Comment: As an addendum to the given answers: to achieve your goal, try `one.__class__.var = 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't change for all of them because doing this: `one.var = 2`, creates a new instance variable
with the same name as the class variable, but only for the instance `one`.
After that, `one` will first find its instance variable and return that, while `two` will only find the class variable and return that.

To change the class variable I suggest two options:

1. create a class method to change the class variable (my preference)
2. change it by using the class directly

```
class MyClass:
    var = 1

    @classmethod
    def change_var(cls, var): 
        cls.var = var


one = MyClass()
two = MyClass()

print(one.var, two.var) # out: 1 1

one.change_var(2)  # option 1
print(one.var, two.var) # out: 2 2

MyClass.var = 3     # option 2
print(one.var, two.var) # out: 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Assignment to an attribute via an  instance *always* creates/updates an instance variable, whether or not a class attribute of the same name exists. To update a class attribute, you must use a reference to the class.

```
>>> type(one).var = 2
>>> print(one.var, two.var)
2 2
```

In practice, `type(one)` might return the *wrong* class to update a particular class attribute, but also in practice, you don't need to change class attributes when you only have an instance of the class available.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `one.var = 2` sets a new **instance** variable called `var`: it doesn't change the **class** variable `var`.

That being said, `one.var` accesses a new **instance** variable, and not the **class** variable.

If both **class** and **instance** have the same variable name, the access to the **instance** variable, is prioritized, shadowing the class variable when accessing the variable via **instance**:

```py
class MyClass:
    var = 1

one = MyClass()
two = MyClass()

print(one.var, two.var) 
one.var = 2 # Adds the new instance variable by object
                # ↓ Accesses the class variable by object 
print(one.var, two.var)
   #     ↑
   # Accesses the new instance variable by object
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 1
```

---

To change the **class** variable `var`, you need to use the **class** itself:

```py
class MyClass:
    var = 1

one = MyClass()
two = MyClass()

print(one.var, two.var) 
MyClass.var = 2 # Changes the class variable by the class name

print(one.var, two.var)
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
```

---

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/how-to-access-static-class-variables-in-python/74493657#74493657) for a similar topic explains more about accessing class variables.

Answer (score 0):

#### Accessing Class variables via its Instances, is not ideal

If both Class and Instance (object) **have variables/attributes with a same name**, accessing such attributes via Instance (object), will always return the variable/attribute from the Instance (object) itself, shadowing the Class variable/attribute: **Instance attributes takes precedence over a Class attributes**, if they have the same names.

You're setting an `instance` variable (attribute) instead of interacting with the `class` variable, as it was mentioned on the comments.

---

#### Side Example

- a Class defined with a variable, accessed via the Class itself

```
class Message: default = "nothing here..."                                     
Message.default                                                                
>>> 'nothing here...'
```

- an instance (object) is created and the Class variable is accessed via instance

```
m = Message()                                                                  
m.default                                                                      
>>> 'nothing here...'
```

- an attribute `default` is defined on the instance

```
m.default = "Say your name."                                                   
m.default                                                                      
>>> 'Say your name.'
```

- the Class variable is updated

```
Message.default = "Anybody there?"                                             
Message.default                                                                
'Anybody there?'
```

- and nothing happens with the attribute `default` from `m` object

```
m.default                                                                      
>>> 'Say your name.'
```

- if the attribute is deleted, then the Class variable is once accessible via instance (object)

```
m.__delattr__("default")                                                       
m.default                                                                      
>>> 'Anybody there?'
```

---

#### Summing up

Safer ways of accessing Class variables via its instances (I recommend the last one):

```
type(m).default                                                         
>>> 'Anybody there?'

m.__class__.default                                                     
>>> 'Anybody there?'
```