# Use object created in a class python

Tags: python, class, object

I have this code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']


class B():
    a = A()
    def foo():
        print(a.new_list)
```

When I type

```
b = B()
b.foo()
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I don't understand why because I already created the object `a` with the `A()` class

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code. I get a different error to the one claimed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access "static" class variables within methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-methods-in-python)